# IntelliJ Update -> get Error by lambda

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lambda

I updated my IntelliJ IDEA this morning and after that I openend my project and suddenly i get an error in my lambda expressions.

First i got this one:

```
Lambda expressions not supported at this language level
```

and then I tried to change the Project Langugage level and afterwards set it back to default. Now i get this one:

```
Error:(39, 46) java: lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.7
  (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)
```

IntelliJ ProjectStructure Options:

[image]

This is my lambda:
And I say it again before I updated IntellJ it worked:

```
response.getData().stream().filter(a -> a.getStart_time() > WTStandards.getUnixTime()).forEach(eventList::add);
```

Answer (score 13):

You have configued your ***Project*** language level, you need also to configure ***Module*** language level. Read more on [Configuring Global, Project and Module SDKs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/configuring-global-project-and-module-sdks.html).

Go to **Project Structure → Module** tab (<kbd>⌘ CMD</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> on *MacOS* or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> on *Windows OS*) and check Language level of your module there:

[image]

You may also need to change the *Java compiler version* as well. Go to **Settings** dialog (<kbd>⌘ CMD</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> on *MacOS* or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> on *Windows OS*), navigate through **Build, Execution, Deployment → Compiler → Java Compiler** (or just type `javac` in the search box on top) and change Java Compiler version as below:

[image]

Comment: Oh thanks, thought I just have to change it in Project Structure. But now I get this sort of error: Error:java: javacTask: source release 1.8 requires target release 1.8

Comment: Found the solution by myself:  File->Settings->Build, Execution, ... -> Compiler -> Java Compiler and there i had to set also Java8